# How to Display Only Filename and FileSize in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

when i try to open an image using axes as button its display filename with source path.

- File Name : C:\Users\Win8\Documents\MATLAB\Test\lena.png
- File Size : 606.09

  [image]

i just want to display filename (red border) only and filesize in KB (blue border) without decimal.

- File Name : lena.png
- File Size : 606

axes1 Callback Code:

```
function axes1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
project = guidata(gcbo);

[imgname, imgpath] = uigetfile({'*.png';}, 'Open an Image')
if imgname==0 % if it is canceled
    imgname=''; % create an empty name
    imgpath=''; % create an empty path
end
if isequal(imgname, 0)
return;
end
eval(['cd ''' imgpath ''';']);
I=imread(fullfile(imgpath, imgname));
set(project.figure1, 'CurrentAxes', project.axes1);
set(imshow(I));
imshow(I);
set(project.figure1, 'Userdata', I);
set(project.axes1, 'Userdata', I);
info = imfinfo(fullfile(imgpath, imgname));
set(project.edit1, 'String', info.Filename);
set(project.edit2, 'String', info.FileSize/1024);
```

any advice how to do it??
i'm using MATLAB R2012a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part: use [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html):

```
[~, fn, ext] = fileparts(info.Filename); %// get filename (no path) and extension
set(project.edit1, 'String', [fn ext])
```

For the second part: use [`round`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/round.html):

```
set(project.edit2, 'String', round(info.FileSize/1024))
```

or maybe explicitly indicate units (kB) in the string:

```
set(project.edit2, 'String', [num2str(round(info.FileSize/1024)) ' kB'])
```

Comment: wow thanks, anyway how to add KB after FileSize in edit2. ex: 606 KB. sorry for silly question, i'm newbie.

Comment: I had just updated answer with that. Telepathy? :-) Check if it works